# How to add methods in dynamic string and call them according to for loop condition?

Tags: java, string, android-studio, for-loop, methods

I want to call multiple methods in a string according to the `for` loop condition.

This code should help you understand what I am looking for:

```
public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
    for (count=0;count<=25;count++){
        if (count==position){
            String methodCall="A"+count+"List()";
            A0List()=methodCall;
        }
    }
}

A0List(){
     //Body 
     //when count=0 this method is called
}

A1List(){
    //body
    //when count=1 this method is called
}

// ...

A25List(){
   //body
   //when count=25 this method is called
}
```

I use this code on my Android app to reduce click listener code.

I am looking for a solution which avoids an if-else-if ladder loop.

Comment: You could do it using reflection but I won't recommend it. Instead, I believe the code in your `AXList()` methods would be quite similar, so you should have just one method and pass the number as a parameter. Can you show the code in a couple of those methods to confirm this?

Comment: Using a adapter to put value in another class or Andorid activity

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking is covered here:
[How do I invoke a Java method when given the method name as a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/160970/how-do-i-invoke-a-java-method-when-given-the-method-name-as-a-string)

But in most situations, preferable to reflection would be explicitly mapping.  This way your function names don't have to be bound to a position by name.  The mapping has to be done somewhere.  I fail to see how the method name is the proper place for that:

```
Map<Integer, Runnable> functionMap = new HashMap<>();
functionMap.put(0, () -> A0List());
functionMap.put(1, () -> {/*A1List body*/});
// etc
functionMap.put(25, () -> someMeaningfulMethodName());
```

Then your function would be:

```
public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
    functionMap.getOrDefault(position, () -> {/* handle incorrect position */}).run();
}
```

Even simpler would be a switch statement:

```
switch(position)
{
    case 0: A0List(); break;
    case 1: A1List(); break;
    // etc
    case 25: A25List(); break;
    default: /* handle unknown position */ break;
}
```

Comment: thanks. But switch and map it is the same as if-else-if ladder loop. I want more utilize

Comment: The mapping has to be done somewhere.  I don't that doing it in the method name is a good idea, but if you must, this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/160970/how-do-i-invoke-a-java-method-when-given-the-method-name-as-a-string